# how to debug angular error with no information

Tags: javascript, angular, debugging

I get an error `ERROR Error: "[object Object]" in my console and my app just has a white screen. It was working fine, and I can't think what I've changed if anything. It shows as being in core.js not my code so how can I debug this?

My app is Angular version 7. Along time ago it was version 2, but has been upgraded over time.

[image]

Comment: try logging in different lifecycle methods

Comment: Jumping from 2 to 7, no wonder you get breaking changes. Did you follow the [upgrade instructions](https://update.angular.io/)?

Comment: @JeremyThille The app has been working for some time as version 7. I just added 2 to 7 to contrast this to version 1, to me 2 to 7 are more or less the same just with incremental changes.

Comment: @prady00 Thanks, but I wonder if there's not a better way than adding console.log everywhere.

Comment: Please add your edit as an answer to help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your object into json format

if you use pipe line easy to print data

> `let item of array | json`

in ngfor loop

Comment: but what object? The problem was that the error showed as being in angular code itself, and didn't show where in my code it originated. What I wanted to know was how to debug in that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had added code which tried to read environment variables from `process.env`. I figured this out by slowly reviewing all code that had gone in to the code base recently. Hope Angular gets better debugging soon. App built successfully with no error, yet failed at run time with no hint as to where in my code it was.